# React to Mapkit object value change

Tags: swift, swift2, mapkit, key-value-observing

I'm looking to react to the mapkit current location dot in real time. I can use LocationManager to get the position in intervals, however the annotation moves in a more fluid way. I want to capture this movement. Is there a way to observer the position of the dot UIView or coordinate than react, in my case with connecting to MKPolyline endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own user location view, then add an observer to it:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(ClubPinAnnotation *)annotation {

    // If the annotation is the user location, create and return our own dot view
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {            
        MKAnnotationView *userView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, -5, 10, 10)];
        userView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        userView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        // Observe its on-screen position
        [userView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"layer.position" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

        return userView;
    }

    ... continue processing the other map annotations
}
```

Then observe the location of the pin on-screen:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    MKAnnotationView *userView = (MKAnnotationView *)object;

    NSLog(@"User view:%@", userView);
}
```

Comment: p.s. sorry I answered in Objective-C but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The animation is likely an interpolated response.  My guess, as I have no research to support this.

You could estimate the animation period, and provide your MkPolyline as a computed value on the interpolation region as a function of time in the animation period.